# Issue with noalias() when using strides

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am using Eigen for a computational fluid dynamics application and I noticed what seems to be a bug. I abstracted the code so that anyone can reproduce it. I am using Eigen 3.3.7.

The following code reproduces the issue

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Eigen"
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
    const int dim = 3;
    const int nb = pow(3, dim);
    const int nq = pow(2, dim);

    vector<double> A(dim*nb);
    for (uint i=0; i<A.size(); i++) A[i] = i;

    vector<double> D(dim*nq*nb);
    for (uint i=0; i<D.size(); i++) D[i] = 2*i;

    vector<double> C(dim*dim*nq, 0.);

    Map< const Matrix<double, dim, Dynamic, RowMajor> >  mat_A(A.data(), dim, nb);

    Map< const Matrix<double, dim, Dynamic, RowMajor>, 0, OuterStride<> >
        mat_B(D.data(), dim, nb, OuterStride<> (nq*nb));

    Map< Matrix<double, dim, Dynamic, RowMajor>, 0, InnerStride<>>
        mat_C(C.data(), dim, dim, InnerStride<> (nq));

    mat_C.noalias() = mat_A * mat_B.transpose();
    cout << mat_C << endl << endl;

    mat_C = mat_A * mat_B.transpose();
    cout << mat_C << endl << endl;
}
```

The output of the code is

```
12402     0     0
31356     0     0
50310     0     0

      12402      164034      315666
      31356      497916      964476
      50310      831798 1.61329e+06
```

The results should be the same. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Dear Kihiro, please explain what you expect the results to be

Comment: Updated my post. The results should be the same with or without noalias() since no memory aliasing occurs between the LHS and RHS.

Comment: The problem seems to come from the results of the matrix mult ignoring the stride in the version with `noalias` (if you look at your `C` vector after the first mult it has the right numbers but not in the right places...)

Comment: The code path of the assignment seems to be different, with the noalias case invoking `paralelize_gemm`, which assume that your values are packed together, hence ignoring the stride

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you know a way to avoid using a temporary while using strides?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved as far as I am concerned by pulling the master branch from the gitlab repository. It might be linked to this [issue](https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/commit/978d1da6a40a127890b73bacd7ed374778e2aacb). Thank you for your help.